# Is there a reason to use HTTP vs HTTPS for a simple site with no inputs?

Tags: http, https

Basically, if I'm gonna be hosting a simple static (or static-ish) site, that takes no user inputs (barring any logging on the server itself), should I still be using HTTPS versus HTTP?

Comment: Your sites should **always** have HTTPS. It's a **huge security concern** if you don't have HTTPS, SEO is impacted, and certificates are free, so there are **no** excuses for not making use of it. Please see [**DoesMySiteNeedHTTPS**](https://doesmysiteneedhttps.com) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, HTTPS has a better security advantage but it also boosts your SEO optimization. Back in 2014, Google announced that websites who switch from HTTP to HTTPS will get a small SEO ranking bumps. Since your site is not taking any user inputs, it's still recommended to use HTTPS over HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons to use HTTPS instead of HTTP, even for a simple site without any user input:

1. **SEO**. Search engine would prefer HTTPS content than HTTP.
2. **HTTP/2**. With HTTPS, you can enable HTTP/2 protocol, which will improve website performance a lot.
3. **User experience**. With HTTP, browser would display a "Not Secure" warning for your website, which brings concern for user.
4. **Extensibility**. Even for a simple website, it can be improved and include user input in future (survey form, user sign-up etc.). It is a good engineering practice to make some preparation in advance, especially when the cost of HTTPS is pretty low today.